# Kafka nack() can another consumer pick it up or will it be returned to the same server?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a producer and a consumer.  I have the consumer set up to create threads for the first three messages and return an

```
acknowledge.nack(6000L);
```

for messages 4, 5, 6, 7, etc.  My understanding and observation is that those messages are redelivered.  My test system only has one consumer.

My question is pretty basic but foundational.  If I have other consumers will they get a chance to pick up the 'nacked' messages or will it only be redelivered back to this exact consumer.  I apologize is this is obvious but I am completely new to this technology.

Comment: Please clarify "other consumers". Are they all unique consumer groups? If so, you'll get messages 1-3 again as well, assuming auto.offset.reset=earliest

Comment: In theory I will have a many consumer part of the same consumer group.  Looking at this value I do have kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest in my config.  But the important thing is that if other consumers are in the same group they will get the nacked messages and I won't get redelivery?

Comment: Consumers in the same group cannot be assigned the same partitions. Anything being acked/nacked is specific to one partition. If your consumer group rebalances, then `auto.offset.reset` property is used to determine offset position, and it defaults to end of every partition, maybe causing you to skip processing data previously sent... If you set to earliest, then you should expect it to reprocess nacked (aka uncommitted) offsets